# MVC 4 Action Link strange Parameter

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, hyperlink, parameters

Hy!

What is this number meaning at the end of my links in mvc4?

for example:
http://localhost:59459/Sports/games?league=FB&_=1424432563533

I mean this: "...&_=1424432563533"

What is this standing for? Can i disable this or is this necessary?

Answer (score 1):

jQuery adds a parameter like that For get requests, and only if the option cache is false: to get around IE's caching (CacheBuster PARAMETER) i.e `cache: false`

```
cache
```

> Default: true, false for dataType 'script' and 'jsonp' If set to
>   false, it will force requested pages not to be cached by the browser.
>   Setting cache to false also appends a query string parameter,
>   "_=[TIMESTAMP]", to the URL.